# Click button not being triggered at the right time? (Rspec + Capybara)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm testing the following:

1. The user create a post (new page), then he is redirected to the show page (the post is saved as **"Published"**).
2. He goes to the edit page, and clicks the **"Save Draft"** button, he is redirected to the show page again.
3. He goes to the edit page again, and now he should see something like: `<p>Status: <span>"Draft"</span></p>` (previously it was  `<p>Status: <span>"Published"</span></p>`)

**spec:**

```
describe "post status" do

  let!(:post) { FactoryGirl.create(:post, user:         user,
                                          title:        "Lorem",
                                          content:      "Lorem Ipsum",
                                          status:       "Published",
                                          #category_id:  category.id,
                                          tag_list:      "#{tag.id}") }
  before do
    sign_in user
    visit edit_post_path(post)
  end

  describe "edit page" do
    it { should have_selector('h1',   text: "Update post") }
    it { should have_selector('span', text: "Published") }
  end

  let(:save_draft) { "Save Draft" }
  let(:publish)    { "Publish" }

  describe "save as draft" do

    before do
      click_button save_draft
      visit edit_post_path(post)
    end

    it { should have_selector('h1',       text: "Update post") }
    it { should_not have_selector('span', text: "Published") }
    it { should have_selector('span',     text: "Draft") }
  end
end

<p class="status">
  <% if @post.status == "Draft" %>
    Status: <span class="label"><%= @post.status %></span>
  <% elsif @post.status == "Published" %>
    Status: <span class="label label-primary"><%= @post.status %></span>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

**edit page:**

```
<p class="status">
  <% if @post.status == "Draft" %>
    Status: <span class="label"><%= @post.status %></span>
  <% elsif @post.status == "Published" %>
    Status: <span class="label label-primary"><%= @post.status %></span>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

The behavior works in the live page but when I run the spec, the test fails:

Failures:

> 1) Post pages show page post status save as draft 
>        Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('span',     text: "Draft") }
>          expected css "span" with text "Draft" to return something
>        # ./spec/requests/post_pages_spec.rb:211:in `block (5 levels) in '
>
> 2) Post pages show page post status save as draft 
>        Failure/Error: it { should_not have_selector('span', text: "Published") }
>          expected css "span" with text "Published" not to return anything
>        # ./spec/requests/post_pages_spec.rb:210:in `block (5 levels) in '

The spec seems to find the text **"Published"** but not **"Draft"** inside the `span` tags (it should find **"Draft"**).

Is the click button being triggered at the wrong time? How to fix that?

**EDIT:**

```
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update_attributes(params[:post]) && params[:commit] == "Publish"
      @post.update_attributes(status: "Published")
      flash[:success] = "Post updated."
      redirect_to @post
    elsif @post.update_attributes(params[:post]) && params[:commit] == "Save Draft"
      @post.update_attributes(status: "Draft")
      flash[:success] = "Post draft updated."
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
    if @post.save && params[:commit] == "Publish"
      @post.update_attributes(status: "Published")
      flash[:success] = "Post published."
      redirect_to @post
    elsif @post.save && params[:commit] == "Save Draft"
      @post.update_attributes(status: "Draft")
      flash[:success] = "Post saved as draft."
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you show the code that updates the status of the post as well?

Comment: @Paul Fioravanti OK, I posted it. Please see my **EDIT**.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't expect this to be a correct answer, I will suggest a couple of things you can do to debug this.

First, if your page is working as expected live, then that means the issue relates to how you wrote the test. First thing I would do is go through your page completing the task live, then view the page source and make sure the html tags match

```
should have_selector("tag", text: "whatever text is in your page source")
```

Second, I would make sure that the pages you visit are the correct pages you want to go to. Doing a quick `rake routes` and going through each page in your browser, then comparing the correct pages you want to go to with the pages you want visited in your test should do it.

Third, did you set subject elsewhere in your test? I don't see it in the test code you provided.

I'll take a deeper look at your code in a couple of hours since I have some other work to do. Let me know the results.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. It took me a whole afternoon figuring out the problem. It seems like the form wasn't validating because I didn't add `tag_list: "#{tag.id}") }` before `click_button save_draft`. Wow, sometimes testing consumes more time than coding.

Comment: It can, but if you plan on making your project big, in the long term tests can be incredibly helpful for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I never thought this would be the problem:

```
 tag_list:      "#{tag.id}") }
```

I had to do this:

```
before do
 tag_list:      "#{tag.id}") }
  click_button save_draft
  visit edit_post_path(post)
end
```

The tags are being added with a `data` attribute. So, the form didn't validate and the `'Published'` attribute didn't change.